# С чего начать настройку непрерывной интеграции (CI) на проекте?

Tags: gitlab, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, githooks, devops

Имеется сервер разработки Win2012 R2, на котором крутится тестовая версия проекта на JavaScript, код хранится в репозитории GitLab'а, проект билдится webpack'ом при запуске npm-скрипта

Решил попробовать реализовать сценарий: обновился репозиторий GitLab'a, за ним обновляется локальный репо на сервере, проект пересобирается и перезапускается.

Сейчас все выполняю руками, что тратит много времени и состоит из рутинных операций - пул из гит-репозитория ветки, запуск "npm run prod"

Понимаю, что много неизвестных в задаче, но подскажите, пожалуйста, ресурсы, рецепты, лучшие практики и инструменты, с которых можно начать изучение CI и реализовать сценарии, подобные вышеприведенному?

Comment: Для начала составьте нумерованный список рутинных действий, чтобы можно было говорить об алгоритме.

Comment: С учетом того, что у вас гитлаб, лучше всего начать с ознакомления с [его возможностями](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/) - в нем уже встроен CI-сервер, который вы можете использовать

Comment: @etki если я правильно понимаю, когда мы будет использовать встроенный CI-сервер, мы привязываемся к экосистеме гитлаба. сможем ли потом безболезненно перейти на другое хранилище?

Comment: Боюсь, недостаточно знаком с гитлабом для ответа на этот вопрос

Comment: @while1pass перейти на другое сможете, но скрипты и конфигурацию CI придется переписывать с нуля. Зато вам не придется админить (или платить за) отдельный сервер CI.

Comment: `npm run prod` что делает? Какой командой вы собираете проект из исходников? Что нужно для запуска проекта на тестовом сервере (сервисы какие-нибудь дернуть, например).

Comment: GitLab у вас .com или сами хостите?

Comment: @NickVolynkin гитлаб свой. сейчас начал с простого) установки дженкинса, который слушает определенный порт, и создании пост-хука на гитлабе. Позже отпишу ответ

Comment: @while1pass я вам очень сильно рекомендую сначала опробовать GitLab CI. Могу дать простой плейбук ansible для его установки.

Comment: @while1pass в гитлабе есть отличная фича Review Apps, удобно деплоить тестовые окружения прямо из мерж-реквеста, а потом вместе с закрытыием реквеста их удалять. Сам сейчас использую.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, поделитесь, пожалуйста

Comment: @edem добавил в ответ последовательность для автоматизации

Answer (score 1):

Как посоветовал @edem в комментариях, необходимо добавить список рутинных действий, которые я хочу автоматизировать, решил начать с простого:

1. После успешно влитого "Pull request" Gitlab сообщает об обновлении ветки на сервер Jenkins
2. Jenkins получает уведомление и стягивает обновленную ветку себе
3. Jenkins запускает powershell команду для сборки проекта. В моем случае `npm run prod`

Для начала установил Jenkins на мой dev-сервер на порту 8081.

Затем, как понимаю, в GitLab необходимо добавить хук на событие `Pull request` который уведомит наш dev-сервер (по порту 8081) об обновлении. Взял из [доков Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) для Jenkins.

`http://<dev-server-ip>:8081/git/notifyCommit?url=https://repo.git`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас остановился на пункте 2, не знаю как создать сценарий, в котором запустится powershell команды для получения ветки и сборки проекта.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто в курсе?

Comment: Дополнять стоит свой вопрос, а в ответах вопросы вообще писать не стоит

Comment: @PeterSamokhin надеюсь, он перерастет в ответ

Comment: Если вы решили работать с Jenkins и у вас конкретный вопрос об этом — стоит опубликовать его именно как вопрос. Это уже совсем другая задача.

Answer (score 1):

Пример разворачивания, используя Gitlab CI:

1. Поставить Gitlab Runner на сервер (для win -
   https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html)
2. Зарегистрировать runner в проекте
   (http://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/)
3. Положить в репозиторий файл `.gitlab-ci.yml` (образец):

   ```
   deploy_master:
       type: deploy  
       before_script:  
           - cd TARGET_DIR  
           - git pull  
       script:  
           - npm run prod  
       only:  
           - master
   ```

**UPDATE**:
gitlab-ci.yml описывает задания и их зависимости. Каждое задание запускается независимо и выполняет содержимое секций `before_script` (подготовка), `script` (сама задача) и `after_script` (завершение).
В примере 1 задание (deploy_master) с типом deploy, в котором указывается, что на этапе подготовки надо обновить код в указанной папке до версии в репозитории, далее запускается основная задача (npm).
Т.к. это разворачивание prod-версии, то добавлен фильтр: задание запускать только при изменении ветки master (можно по тегам/веткам)

Comment: Если бы вы ещё рассказали, что и при каких условиях делает этот `.gitlab-ci.yml`...

Comment: Отлично. Плюс уже поставил, второй раз не могу )